# Engine squealing

Tags: troubleshooting

After replacing the belt and the idler pulley, the 6 cylinder 2005 Chevrolet Silverado still has a high pitch squeal.  Have not checked the power steerinmg or water pump to see if the noise is coming from there.  What is the fix?

Answer (score 2):

When you have the accessory belt off the vehicle, you can spin each accessory by hand and see if they feel 'normal' or one has some roughness when it spins that indicates a bad bearing.

Or, with the engine running *carefully* place a long, flat head screwdriver on a each accessory (avoiding any moving parts).  Press the handle end of the screwdriver against your ear.  The screwdriver will act like a stethoscope, allowing you to pinpoint the source of the noise.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll have to find the source.  There's a lot of things that can make a belt-like squeal.  I've heard it from fuel pumps and even an oil pump before.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to provide more information.

1. Where is the noise coming from?  Engine bay?  Front, middle or rear?  High or low?
2. Is the noise constant, only at start-up / when cold or only sometimes when driving?  Is it a constant pitch or dependent on revs?
3. Any other symptoms?  Odd gauge behavior or readings?

From looking over your engine, I'd worry about the power steering the most.  I had an odd power steering problem not too long ago after a kinetic encounter with a deer.  The pump was starved after the impact due to loss of fluid but wasn't replaced (no visible damage).  After getting the car back, everything seemed fine while driving until I'd been on the road for a bit.  After the car was warm, though, I'd get odd noises and really strange hydraulic behavior.

Brian is right, though: go and listen to the pumps on the car and see whether the noise is actually coming from one of them.